# Is there way to use apache velocity template file with any HTML templating engine like mustache or handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, velocity, template-engine

Is there any template engine js library available by which i can use apache velocity template file to generate HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any JS library which could use apache velocity templates to produce HTML. However, we did find a NPM which could be used to generate HTML page using apache velocity template. Here is URL => [Velocity NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/velocity)