# use velocity template engine in js page

Tags: node.js, liferay, frontend, browserify, velocity

i know there's some nodejs modules to use apache velocity in node like those addresses in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365411/2079428) question's response.

could be done to use it as a, says, mustache replacement via, maybe, browserify.js?

how would you do that as a workflow?

I suspect it would be a better implementation on Liferay's frontend template development, so the frontender can serve to the java team html already velocity templating aware.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use [velocityjs](https://github.com/shepherdwind/velocity.js) on browser after using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) on it.

**Installation**

First install velocityjs in your node_modules

`$> npm install velocityjs`

Now from your project (where the node_modules mentioned above exists) use browserify

`browserify -r velocityjs  > velocity.js`

This will create a velocity.js file that you can include in your website directly. If you don't have browserify then do `npm install -g browserify`

**Usage**

In your webpage js file first require velocityjs

`var velocityjs = require("velocityjs");`

Now to get the templated html do

`var renderedString = velocityjs.render(initialString,context)`

Note that velocity does not care if your initial string was html or not, you need to ensure that