# Using velocity template and JSON to generate HTML?

Tags: java, json, velocity, template-engine

I need a direct way to use velocity template and JSON string data to generate HTML data.
For example:

`String mergedHtml = Velocity.someMethodToParseTemplate("VelocityTemplate.vm" ,String JsonString");`

How can it be done ? Please suggest the code for "someMethodToParseTemplate"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to parse the JSON string (for instance using the [org.json library](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)) and then to build a VelocityContext out of the parsing result.

Let say you have the following template:

```
<html>
  <body>
    $name is $age years old and lives $address.streetAddress, ${address.city}.
    <br/>
    $name's friends:
    <ul>
    #foreach($friend in $friends)
      <li>$friend.name, who is $friend.age years old</li>
    #end
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can merge it against a JSON string like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonPublisher
{
  protected VelocityEngine velocity;

  public JsonPublisher()
  {
    // init velocity                                                                                                                                                                                            
    // default resource loader is a file loader on the current directory                                                                                                                                        
    velocity = new VelocityEngine();
    velocity.init();
  }

  public String publish(String templatePath, String jsonString) throws IOException
  {
    // translate json string to velocity context                                                                                                                                                                
    // (we only need to convey the properties of the root object)                                                                                                                                               
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    for(String key : jsonObj.keySet())
    {
      context.put(key, jsonObj.get(key));
    }

    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    velocity.mergeTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8", context, writer);
    writer.flush();

    return writer.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
    {
      String str = "{ \"name\": \"Alice\", \"age\": 20, \"friends\": "+
        "[ { \"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":21 }, { \"name\":\"Carol\", \"age\":19 } ], " +
        "\"address\": { \"streetAddress\": \"100 Wall Street\", \"city\": \"New York\" } }";
      String result = new JsonPublisher().publish("template.vm", str);
      System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to wrap your JSON object under some root property of the context, let's say `$json`, then it's even simpler:

```
....
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("json", jsonObj);        
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice descriptive answer ! Had a query , so now if the JSON is large, wont it slow down the conversion?

Comment: If the JSON is large, the method may not be appropriate, but HTML may not be appropriate either, since big volumes aren't meant to be uploaded to browsers. It really depends upon what you call *large*. Above a certain size, only stream processing (which does line by line parsing+publishing, à la *sed/awk*) is pertinent, and very often writing your own is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

If the main objective of Html is to be shown in the browser then it might be better to use a client side velocity rendering engine and the json + template separately to the client.

In case your client is a browser you can use use [velocityjs](https://github.com/shepherdwind/velocity.js) on browser.
Essentially it comes down to something like `var renderedHtml = velocityjs.render(htmlTemplate,jsonData)`. Then you can set the `renderedHtml` as `innerHtml` of some dom element.

Check my [another answer for more detailed steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433982/use-velocity-template-engine-in-js-page/38887387#38887387)